# I can't get details from a client he gives me [object Object] using angular and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am a beginner in angular firebase, I followed a training, angular firebase, I want details of a client, but it gives me in the client console: [object Object].

**list-clients.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let client of clients"> 
  <td class="text-right">
     <a routerLink="/client/{{ client.id }}" class="btn btn-info "><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**client.service.ts**

```
getClient(id:string){
    return this.clientsCollection.doc(id).valueChanges();
  }
```

**details-client.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.clientService.getClient(this.id).subscribe((client:any) => {
       this.client = client;
       console.log("client est : " + this.client);
     });  
  }
```

Comment: Use `console.dir(this.client)` to see the actual properties. That should guide you along.

Comment: You can use log as well, just don’t concatenate it with a string. Use a comma in that case: console.log("client est : ", this.client);

Comment: @MikeOne yeh exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the **this.client** property is of type Object. The console.log() method will show you the object properties if you pass the object alone instead of concatenating it to a string. You could also use your debugger and stop execution at the **this.client = client** line to see the value.